# How to write html custom attribute in less use Mixins

Tags: less

how to write html custom attribute in .less Use **Mixins** for example

```
[margin="2"]{margin:2px;}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do mate? Are you trying to generate classes where the `margin` is assigned based on the value for the margin attribute in HTML? You would have to statically generate as many classes as the no. of different margins require. Unless Less is used in Client side (which is not recommended), I can't see any way for Less to know what value the attribute has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should explain why you want to use Less in this situation. Notice that Less only compiles static CSS.

You can use a Less mixin to dynamically built your CSS rules:

```
.createmargins(@i) {
& when (@i > 1) {
.createmargins(@i - 1);
}
[margin="@{i}"] { margin: unit(@i,px); }
}

.createmargins(100);
```

outputs:

```
[margin="1"] {
  margin: 1;
}
[margin="2"] {
  margin: 2;
}
[margin="3"] {
  margin: 3;
}
```

and so on......

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyXEgg

The above possible generates a lot of unused CSS classes. Alternatively consider using jQuery (or jvascript) on DOM ready:

```
$("[margin]").each(function(){

 $(this).css('margin',$(this).attr('margin') + 'px');

});
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rawKjz